# Why is formic acid more acidic than benzoic acid?

Tags: organic-chemistry

**Why is formic acid(pKa=3.751)  more acidic than benzoic acid(pKa=4.204)?**

Here's what I understand:

1) Phenyl ring is electron withdrawing therefore it should decrease electron density on oxygen thus stabilizing the anion obtained after deprotonation. Considering this argument, benzoic acid should be more acidic than formic acid.

2) [image]

It looks like resonance of phenyl ring with carboxylate should destabilize the anion and therefore, formic acid should be a better acid. But the "aromatic ring is so thermodynamically stable that the phenyl ring donating electrons to the carboxylate is not a major resonance structure".

Considering the two above factors, benzoic acid should be stronger than formic acid. Then why it's not?

Comment: Related: [Comparing acidities of substituted and aromatic carboxylic acids](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/7591/7951)